# Design Pattern in java unrecognized

Tags: java, design-patterns, inputstream

i had the question of what is the name of the design pattern of the code below.

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("X.zip");  
BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(bin);
```

can anyone help me ? thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a decorator pattern.

Each new instance created adds in a dynamic way a new behavior to an existing instance.
It is dynamic as the behavior is added at runtime and not in the class itself.

In your example, you create a simple `FileInputStream` with basic features that you decorate with a `BufferedInputStream` that add the buffering behavior and you finish by decorating the `BufferedInputStream` instance with a `ZipInputStream` that provides compression features.

You can also write your code in this way :

```
ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("X.zip")));
```

Both `BufferedInputStream` and `ZipInputStream` derive from the `FilterInputStream` abstract class that is designed to enrich behavior of `InputStream` instances.
The javadoc explains it :

> A FilterInputStream contains some other input stream, which it uses as
>   its basic source of data, possibly transforming the data along the way
>   or providing additional functionality. The class FilterInputStream
>   itself simply overrides all methods of InputStream with versions that
>   pass all requests to the contained input stream. Subclasses of
>   FilterInputStream may further override some of these methods and may
>   also provide additional methods and fields.